# Metal pipe of under bathroom sink

Tags: plumbing

Metal pipe to the left came out of the wall and became longer than the one to the right. What could have happened here?

[image]

Comment: so what ? is it working, what is the question

Comment: Photos woukd help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ruskes the pipes are not leaking and are working fine. Just not sure if the position of the pipe is something I have to be worried about.

Comment: The biggest concern is if there is leaking _in_ the wall. You'd need to look at and monitor the ceiling from the floor below to ensure it's staying dry.

Comment: @FreeMan thank you for the advise.